# Postgres: DISABLE TRIGGER ALL and ON UPDATE CASCADE

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger, cascade

It seems like when I

```
ALTER TABLE foo DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
DELETE FROM foo;
```

The deletions don't get cascaded to other tables with

```
FOREIGN KEY ("fooId") REFERENCES "foo"("id") ON DELETE CASCADE
```

constraints, but I can't find anything in the documentation about this. 
 I also don't see any triggers I didn't create in

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.triggers;
```

I'm guessing `ON UPDATE`/`ON DELETE` are implemented internally as triggers (which aren't visible in pgAdmin)?  Does anyone know where this is documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertable.html):

> `DISABLE/ENABLE [ REPLICA | ALWAYS ] TRIGGER`
>   These forms configure the firing of trigger(s) belonging to the table. A disabled trigger is still known to the system, but is not executed when its triggering event occurs. For a deferred trigger, the enable status is checked when the event occurs, not when the trigger function is actually executed. ***One can disable or enable a single trigger specified by name, or all triggers on the table, or only user triggers (this option excludes internally generated constraint triggers such as those that are used to implement foreign key constraints or deferrable uniqueness and exclusion constraints)***. Disabling or enabling internally generated constraint triggers requires superuser privileges; it should be done with caution since of course the integrity of the constraint cannot be guaranteed if the triggers are not executed.

Comment: ah, good catch, I must have tried to find that with `⌘-F DISABLE TRIGGER` and failed...

Comment: Also, `pg_trigger` should display internally generated triggers:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/catalog-pg-trigger.html